# Flutter: download dart code and create class instance dynamically at runtime

Tags: flutter, dart, dynamic, runtime, code-generation

In my app I want a option to have user to download dart code that contains a class and which extends a baseclass defined in the app and override it's methods.

I need to create the instance of that class after the downloading is done and call it's methods.

Comment: This isn't javascript.  A running dart application has no access to compile new code, except as an Isolate.spawnUri, which will have very limited application.